# weird jQuery + Chrome issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I had trouble with adjusting the width dynamicly based on the width of a different element. So I made a small piece of javascript to fix that for me, it was suposed to be an experiment, but a weird issue caught my attention..

```
var adjustTo = $(this).attr('data-adjust-width-to'),
    totalWidth = $(this).parent().width(),
    targetWidth = $(this).parent().find(adjustTo).width(),
    newWidth = totalWidth - targetWidth;

$(this).width(newWidth);
```

This works just fine in firefox, safari and even IE7. However, when I use it in Chrome, it claims targetWidth is 0, even though it's not when I use the console to check the element it's calling.

I managed to fix it... by putting the whole thing inside a setTimeout with 0 delay...

I'd think it has something to do with the rendering not being done but since the code is put in document.ready() function.. that shouldn't be the case, right?

Who knows what the cause of this is issue is?

Comment: can we have a jsfiddle of the complete code working?

Answer (score 0):

Its not usual, but try splitting up the `var` calls:

```
var adjustTo = $(this).attr('data-adjust-width-to');
var totalWidth = $(this).parent().width();
var targetWidth = $(this).parent().find(adjustTo).width();
var newWidth = totalWidth - targetWidth;

$(this).width(newWidth);
```

Comment: How will that make ***any*** difference?

Comment: @Matt -- chrome might not know of `adjustTo` when you are setting `targetWidth`

Comment: @Neal, if that is the solution, then Chrome has a serious bug in it's javaccript engine.. but I'll try just to make sure. EDIT: No, doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var adjustTo = $(this).attr('data-adjust-width-to'),
    totalWidth = $(this).parent().width(),
    targetWidth = $(this).parent().find('#' + adjustTo).width(),
    newWidth = totalWidth - targetWidth;

$(this).width(newWidth);
```

I guess `adjustTo` is an ID pointing to some element. Though IE doesn't really care about the `#`s, WebKit (Chrome) really does.

Comment: in my particular case, adjustTo was a class, so adjustTo already started with a dot. So I'm afraid that that isn't the solution

Comment: If it is a class, you're doing it wrong. A class doesn't point to one specific element, but a group of elements (though a group can contain only one element). Technically, `width()` can't be determined on a group. jQuery instead returns the `width()` of the first element in the group (which may not work very well in Chrome ...). Could you try replacing it with IDs instead?

Comment: He only finds one element, I've checked $(this).parent().find('#' + adjustTo) in the console to see what Chrome thinks it is, but there everything is fine, even the width is correct. Possibly this has the same cause as why putting it in a setInterval(..., 0) works aswell